# How to solve the "CASCADE() missing required positional arguments" TypeError

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and Python. I have created some models in Django, and now can no longer run the application because of the following error:

"TypeError: CASCADE() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'collector', 'field', 'sub_objs', and 'using'"

Here is the model code:

```
class Lifter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    age = models.IntegerField(max_length=100);
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1);
    person_photo = models.CharField(max_length=1000);

def __str__(self):
    return self.name + ' - ' + self.gender

class Results(models.Model):
    lifter = models.ForeignKey(Lifter, on_delete=models.CASCADE())
```

Any idea on what is wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Just replace `CASCADE()` with `CASCADE`:**

```
class Results(models.Model):
    lifter = models.ForeignKey(Lifter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

[Example with ForeignKey from Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)

Comment: Completely missed this even though Pycharm was shouting and pointing it out