# Can't syncdb because CASCADE() missing arguments

Tags: python, django, python-3.7

I am testing Django for the first time to create my own to do list.
All has been working fine so far until I synchronise to my sqlite3 database with

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

I have managed to debug all the errors so far. The error I cant seem to debug is

> TypeError: CASCADE() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'collector', 'field', 'sub_objs', and 'using'

**Here is the model code:**

```
class Item(models.Model):
  worktasks = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  focus = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  #...
  todo_list = models.ForeignKey('Todo', on_delete=models.CASCADE())

def __str__(self):
    return self.worktasks + '-' + self.lessons
```

I've tried removing the brackets "()" after CASCADE which resulted in the output

> Unknown command: 'syncdb'

I am working on Pycharm - Python Version 3.7

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: I used this thread as a reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46299242/how-to-solve-the-cascade-missing-required-positional-arguments-typeerror

Comment: @GwynBleidD My Django Version is 2.1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fix with removing brackets is correct, but this is only half of the problem. The second half is that you're trying to use a command that doesn't exist. `syncdb` is no longer present in new Django (it was removed in Django 1.9). Instead of it, you should use the migrations system. Take look at [this documentation page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/).

Comment: thank you for your response :) When I try `migrate` I get the same error message

Comment: You should also remove `()` after `CASCADE`, as you've done above.